# Как реализовать функцию изменения записи по времени?

Tags: laravel

Каждая запись имеет поле `end_at` с индивидуальным значением, при достижении этой даты должна выполняться функция изменения некоторых параметров записи. Как это реализовать? $schedule не подходит, или я чего-то не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мало информации. Поле где? Что за переменная? Но с прочитаного рискну предположить, что вам нужно изменять данные в базе по достижении даты из столбца `end_at`. Для этого используйте планировщик задач CRON, который будет каждый день или час запускать функцию которая будет проверять таблицу смотреть те строки где есть дата нужная и выполнять нужную функцию.